# Partition a LVM disk

Tags: partitioning, disk, lvm

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed.
I want to add partitions table to a LVM disk of 465 GB.

I would like to make two partitions without loosing any data. Gparted is showing that the whole 465 GB of the disk is used but I have over 150 GB left.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

LVM utils might help - but still can cause data loss.
Anyway - read about lvreduce for a good start.
You'd better make backup first and then repartition disks.